# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (180,180,3) into shape (1,3,180,180)

Tags: arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get an image shape of (1,3,180,180) from original shape, which is (1224, 1842, 3). I've tried specifying the shape like this:

```
im_cv = cv.imread('test.jpg')

im_cv = cv.resize(im_cv, (1,3,180,180))
```

But get the error

```
 File "/Users/lucasjacaruso/Desktop/hawknet-openvino/experiment.py", line 47, in <module>
    im_cv = cv.resize(im_cv, (1,3,180,180)) 
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3-openvino) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 4
>  - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 4
```

However, the model will not accept anything other than (1,3,180,180). If I simply specify the shape as (180,180), it's not accepted by the model:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (180,180,3) into shape (1,3,180,180)
```

How can I get the shape to be (1,3,180,180)?

Many thanks.

Comment: The second argument of [`cv.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) is a tuple where the **two** new dimensions (width and height) are specified. You are giving four dimensions which doesn't make too much sense - what are your new dimensions supposed to represent?

Comment: Looks like `im_cv` is a typical image array, with shape (180,180,3), where 3 is the number of color channels.  I haven't used `cv`, but I don't think `resize` can be used to change it to a (1,3,180,180) shape, where the channels dimension has been move to the front.  Reread the `resize` docs, and don't surprised if you get errors when doing something that isn't documented.

Answer (score 1):

`resize` is to change the image dimensions, e.g. to change the image from `(180,180,3)` to say `(300,300,3)`.
You need to add a new dimension with [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis). Further, as `imread` will return the depth (color) dimension as axis 2, you need to [`move`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) the axis:

```
im_cv = np.moveaxis(im_cv, 2, 0)[np.newaxis]
```